# カッコのないジェネレーター表記？

Tags: python, python3

`list(for x in range(10))`や，`''.join(for elem in elements)`などでは，`list`,`join`の引数は何として扱われているのでしょうか．
`list([for x in range(10)])`と同義ですか，それとも`list((for x in range(10)))`でしょうか．

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `list(for x in range(10))`や，`''.join(for elem in elements)`などでは，list,joinの引数は何として扱われているのでしょうか．

仮に`list(x for x in range(10))`や`''.join(elem for elem in elements)`とした場合、
これらlistやjoinの内部に記述されたものはご推察の通り、カッコのないジェネレーター表記です。

> `list([for x in range(10)])`と同義ですか，それとも`list((for x in range(10)))`でしょうか．

`list(x for x in range(10))`と同義なのは**後者**です。
以下にコードを示します。

### コード

```python
a = list(x for x in range(10))
b = [x for x in range(10)]
c = list([x for x in range(10)])
d = (x for x in range(10))
e = list(d)
f = list((x for x in range(10)))

# generatorをlistでキャスト
print('aの型：{}, 値：{}'.format(type(a), a))

# リスト内包表記
print('bの型：{}, 値：{}'.format(type(b), b))

# リスト内包表記をリストでキャスト
print('cの型：{}, 値：{}'.format(type(c), c))

# generator
print('dの型：{}, 値：{}'.format(type(d), d))

# generatorをlistでキャスト(aと同じ)
print('eの型：{}, 値：{}'.format(type(e), e))

# generatorをlistでキャスト(aと同じ)
print('fの型：{}, 値：{}'.format(type(f), f))

# generatorを直接確認
print(type(x for x in range(10)))
print(x for x in range(10))

print(''.join(str(elem) for elem in a))
```

### 実行結果

```shell
aの型：<class 'list'>, 値：[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
bの型：<class 'list'>, 値：[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
cの型：<class 'list'>, 値：[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
dの型：<class 'generator'>, 値：<generator object <genexpr> at 0x103667b30>
eの型：<class 'list'>, 値：[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
fの型：<class 'list'>, 値：[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
<class 'generator'>
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x103667a50>
0123456789
```

また、一般的にジェネレーターの方が単なるリストよりも、メモリサイズや処理が高速となる場合が多いです。ご参考までに。
[Pythonでジェネレータを使用してメモリ効率の高いプログラムを作成する。](https://ichi.pro/python-de-jyenere-ta-o-shiyoshite-memori-koritsu-no-takai-puroguramu-o-sakuseisuru-80836849663398)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます．

Comment: ジェネレーターを変数に代入する際などは，ブラケットで囲む必要がありますが，これはパーサがfor文と取り違えて解釈してしまうためでしょうか．

Comment: 括弧()で囲む必要があるのは、おっしゃる通りパーサがfor文と取り違えてしまうためだと考えられます。これは変数に代入する際、代入(`=`)の前に右辺の評価を行うためです。右辺の評価順については私も知識不足で根拠を示すことは叶いませんが、実行結果を見る限り、以下の順番で動いていると考えられます。「()がついているため変数と解釈」->「文法を確認」->「generator classと型を解釈」->「generatorインスタンスを生成」

Answer (score 2):

公式ドキュメントだと

https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions

> 関数の唯一の引数として渡す場合には、丸括弧を省略できます。

のところですね。